# What is the best flow to store an image in CDN

Tags: node.js, image, express, upload, cdn

I have a website created using Node Express, this website serves functionality where user can upload an image and it will be stored locally in server folder and the path will be saved in database.

The problem is the images size is taking too much space on the server disk, so i need to use cdn as a storage for those images and to show the image to the user. The problem is i don't know what is the proper end-to-end flow to store this image to cdn.

The end-to-end flow  means the customer upload the picture , the server save it, and can be used again when the user need to see it.

My thought is, when the user uploaded the image, then the server save it first locally, the image path, there will be cron running to store the image to CDN, at the end the image stored in the server will be deleted after success store the image to CDN.
Is that the correct way? or there are any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this

- store images on a cheap storage for long term like s3. this serve as source of truth.
- configure cdn to use the s3 url or your server as source => you don't neeed to upload to cdn.
- bonus: create an image resizer service to sit in front of the source and configure cdn to use the image resizer service as source. this way, it will reduce the load to your resizer service

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Tran answer, you can perform some optimizations.
For example, converting to WebP image format which can reduce the size.
Also, you can look at Image CDNs available which are optimized for images. Following article can be helpful for you

https://imagekit.io/blog/what-is-image-cdn-guide/